# Kindle - Get Quiet Time Setting

Tags: settings, kindle

I need to get the quiet time setting so my app will not play any sounds when the user has Quiet Time turned on in their Kindle.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I was hoping it would be simple as Settings.isQuietTimeOn but I can't find anything about this.

Thanks,

Chris